# How to calculate values from each line?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find a way to read each line(like mentioned below) and addition the values after the '='

```
NumberOfCores=4
NumberOfLogicalProcessors=4

NumberOfCores=4
NumberOfLogicalProcessors=4

NumberOfCores=4
NumberOfLogicalProcessors=4
```

What I am looking for?
Script should be able to read each line which contains 'NumberOfLogicalProcessors' and gives the numeric output of the addition number which is '12' in this case.

The code I have written so far:

```
var lines= abovelines.split('\n');
for(var i = 0;i <lines.length;i++){
    console.log(lines[i]);
}
```

Comment: `console.print(lines[i].split("=")[1]);`

Comment: In your `for` loop, couldnt you grab the numbers you want with a regex expression, put them in an array, and then add all the elements of the resulting array after your `for` loop is done running?

Comment: @pavlos Thanks for the reply. I only need 'NumberOfLogicalProcessors' values to be calculated

Answer (score 0):

You have found out how to get each line by splitting by line breaks. Now all you have to do is to split each line by `=` sign. Like this:

```
var lines= abovelines.split('\n');
var sum = 0;
for(var i = 0;i < lines.length; i++){
    var lineSplit = lines[i].split("=");
    if (lineSplit[0] === 'NumberOfLogicalProcessors') {
       sum += (+lineSplit[1]);
    }
}
console.log('Total NumberOfLogicalProcessors ' + sum);
```

This statement `+lineSplit[1]` is casting the string number to a numeric data type.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I only need 'NumberOfLogicalProcessors' values to be calculated

Comment: Edited the answer. The sum should come as 12 :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here a working example:

```js
const txt = `NumberOfCores=4
NumberOfLogicalProcessors=4

NumberOfCores=4
NumberOfLogicalProcessors=4

NumberOfCores=4
NumberOfLogicalProcessors=4`;

const lines = txt.replace(/(^[ \t]*\n)/gm, "").split('\n');

const result = {};

for(const line of lines) {
  const [text, value] = line.split("=")
  result[text] = (result[text] || 0) + parseInt(value)
}

console.log('All key values: ', result)

console.log('Number of Cores: ', result['NumberOfCores'])

console.log('Number of Procesors: ', result['NumberOfLogicalProcessors'])
```

Here you have all the key values and if you want, you can access specific one by key, like this:

`result['NumberOfLogicalProcessors']`

or

`result['NumberOfCores']`

Answer (score 0):

```
var NumberOfLogicalProcessors = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
{
   var newArray = lines[i].split('=');
   if (newArray.length > 1 && newArray[0] == 'NumberOfLogicalProcessors')
   {
      NumberOfLogicalProcessors = NumberOfLogicalProcessors + parseInt(newArray[1]);
   }
}
console.log(NumberOfLogicalProcessors);
```

Comment: Thanks@Anh-Tuan N.

Answer (score 0):

Regex seems vary suitable to your usecase.

```js
let input = `NumberOfCores=4
NumberOfLogicalProcessors=4

NumberOfCores=4
NumberOfLogicalProcessors=4

NumberOfCores=4
NumberOfLogicalProcessors=4`;

let sums = input
    .match(/\w+=\d+/g)
    .map(a => a.match(/(?<key>\w+)=(?<value>\d+)/).groups)
    .reduce((sums, {key, value}) => {
      sums[key] = (sums[key] || 0) + parseInt(value);
      return sums;
    }, {});

console.log(sums);
console.log(sums.NumberOfLogicalProcessors);
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a good situation to use regular expressions, (syntax is debatable):

```js
const string = `NumberOfCores=4
NumberOfLogicalProcessors=4
NumberOfCores=4
NumberOfLogicalProcessors=4
NumberOfCores=4
NumberOfLogicalProcessors=4`;

const regEx = /(?:NumberOfLogicalProcessors)\s?=+\s?([0-9])/g

let result = 0;

for ( const match of string.match( regEx ) ) {
  result += Number( regEx.exec( match )[ 1 ] );
  regEx.lastIndex = 0; // reset index for next iteration
}

console.log( result );
```